# Processar String para ler HTML

Tags: javascript, html5, vue.js

Estou desenvolvendo uma rede social em Vue.js que precisa retornar no corpo de um dos seus componentes uma propriedade (props).

O componente é o título de uma postagem.

```
<div>
        {{description}}
</div>
```

Porém, este texto está armazenado em html e ao recuperá-lo ele retorna o html em forma de texto em vez de processar as tags. Como faço para que ele processe o html?

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#HTML):

> As chaves duplas interpretam os dados como texto simples, e não HTML. Para que você exiba HTML, utilize a diretiva v-html:

Ou seja, a interpolação através de `{{ expressao }}` sempre converterá para textos (como se você estivesse usando a propriedade `innerText` do Javascript "puro").

Se você quer processar uma string como HTML, você deve utilizar a propriedade `v-html`.

Dessa forma:

```
<template>
  <div v-html="valor"></div>
</template>



<script>
 export default {
      data() {
           return {
               valor: 'minha string com <b>bold</b>'
           }
     }
}
</script>
```

> [...] Note que você não pode utilizar a diretiva v-html para compor templates parciais, porque o Vue não é uma engine baseada em templates através de String. Em vez disso, componentes são a maneira indicada como peça fundamental de composição e reutilização de elementos de interface.